# Can't create Func expression for ordering LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, func

I receive this parameter from my request:

```
sort=homeCountry
```

I need to sort by whatever column is sent to the `sort` parameter, so I created a method like so:

```
string sort = "homeCountry";
Func<PaymentRateTrip, string> orderBy = (
    x => sort == "homeCountry" ? x.HomeCountry :
        sort == "hostCountry" ? x.HostCountry :
            sort == "homeLocation" ? x.HomeLocation :
                sort == "hostLocation" ? x.HostLocation :
                    x.HomeLocation
);
```

This works correctly.

However, the columns above are all strings.  But, I also need to add decimal columns like so:

```
string sort = "homeCountry";
Func<PaymentRateTrip, string> orderBy = (
    x => sort == "homeCountry" ? x.HomeCountry :
        sort == "hostCountry" ? x.HostCountry :
            sort == "homeLocation" ? x.HomeLocation :
                sort == "hostLocation" ? x.HostLocation :
                    sort == "oneWayRate" ? x.oneWayRate :
                    x.HomeLocation
);
```

It gives me an error on the `x.HostLocation` that says:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'decimal?'

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?  I am looking for:

- A way that will work.
- A way that is readable (something like a switch case).

**Edit:** PaymentRateTrip.cs

```
public class PaymentRateTrip
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public Guid HomeCountryId { get; set; }
    public string HomeCountry { get; set; }
    public Guid HomeLocationId { get; set; }
    public string HomeLocation { get; set; }
    public Guid? HostCountryId { get; set; }
    public string HostCountry { get; set; }
    public Guid? HostLocationId { get; set; }
    public string HostLocation { get; set; }
    public decimal? OneWayRate { get; set; }
    public decimal? RoundTripRate { get; set; }
    public Guid? OneWayCurrencyId { get; set; }
    public Guid? RoundTripCurrencyId { get; set; }       

}
```

Comment: Please, don't use this many ternary operators, it doesn't make your code more clear in this scenario.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg What do you recommend?  I am already asking for a better way (I literally said, "Is there a better way").

Comment: Sort what? A list of PaymentRateTrip?

Comment: @DaveBish Yes, sorry - the result set is a list of PaymentRateTrip.  Thanks.

Comment: Please add the definition for `PaymentRateTrip`.  That will help us to determine the root cause a lot easier.

Comment: Look at this would maybe help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd just make an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<PaymentRateTrip> Sort(this IEnumerable<PaymentRateTrip> list, string sort)
{
    switch (sort)
    {
        case "homeCountry":
            return list.OrderBy(x => x.Whatever);
        case "somethingElse":
            return list.OrderBy(x => x.Whatever);

        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: It being an extension method isn't really relevant here (not that it's wrong, it's just not what solves the problem).  What's relevant is that you have a static series of selector delegates that you dynamically choose between, rather than a single delegate that compares on a dynamically chosen value.

Comment: This is what I ended up with for a similar problem. I went down the route of trying to generate an `Expression` based on the string passed in and matching to a property by reflection then.... this was far easier.

Comment: @Servy yeah, you're right of course - I've tried to fall into the trap of making this all dynamic in the past - It's easier & better performing in this case to just bite-the-bullet, and do it statically IMO

Answer (score 1):

It might seem to simple but just do this

```
        var prop = typeof(PaymentRateTrip).GetProperty(sort);
        var ordered = lst.OrderBy(p => prop.GetValue(p));
```

this works as long as the sort name is part of the object.
In your case the function is (p => prop.GetValue(p))